# NFC not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc

I have a Nokia Lumia 820 device. While I run NFC test app to it, the output window shows `exited with code 259 (0x103)`

Full debug output is

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{D86D77EF-53AA-4B7D-95C4-450B169C3814}\Install\Test NFC.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x7b8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x80c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

My app code is

```
var proximityDevice = Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
            if (proximityDevice != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("YES"); 
            }// at least one proximity device installed } 
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NOOOOO");
            }
```

I am with Amber update and in GDR3 preview. and take a look at this screen also.
[image]

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887864/what-is-a-thread-exit-code

Comment: @Sorceri I had a look but I need a very specific answer. and I need to know why the debugger option `'Just My Code'` is enabled

Comment: "thread...has exited with code" messages are normal; is there some specific problem you are having?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I have programmed the above code to a button tap, and its not showing any message boxes. I have installed NFC writer app from Nokia, while I open that app, it notifies me to turn-off Aeroplane mode while the phone is not in Aeroplane mode

Comment: If it's not showing any messages boxes, it's not executing.  You've got a simple `if` that shows one of two messages boxes if the code is executed at all.

Comment: Because the issue persists even with the Nokia Writer app, I suspect there might be a hardware issue with the phone itself. Two things to try out - try to catch exceptions in your code, if something doesn't somehow slip out. Secondly - test the code in emulator - http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Code/2013/04/01/how-to-use-emulators-to-develop-nfc-features-on-wp8/ . That will either confirm or disprove my hypothesis :-) .

Comment: @MZetko will there be any problem with GDR 3 preview?

Comment: Well, it 'could' be, but I have not yet seen something like this reported, so I don't know. You could check that with the Windows Phone on-line developer support, if they have seen similar issue before