# Threads spun with Task.Run always exit with exit code 259

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

As a simple example I have a WPF application with a single button on the Main Window and code behind thus:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task<bool>.Run(() => this.DoOnThread());
    }

    async Task<bool> DoOnThread()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MyTestThread";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I break at "return true"  via VisualStudio threads window I can get the ThreadID, if I continue and let the code run to completion and wait a little till the thread exits, I get "The thread 0x9ad34 has exited with code 259 (0x103)"  displayed in the VS output window.

What am I doing wrong and how do I ensure I get a thread exit code of 0?

Comment: Exit Code 259 is "STILL_ACTIVE". I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Agreed with Adam... what are you trying to do?  Tasks run on the threadpool, those threads stay alive and wait for work.

Comment: It's just that I see these exit coded is Visual Studio output and was curious as to what was causing it.  my above simple, crude example was my attempt at getting an answer, nothing more.  Thank you.

Comment: [Tip](http://damieng.com/blog/2014/02/05/8-visual-studio-debugging-tips-debug-like-a-boss): right-click and uncheck module/thread/process messages. They're almost always just noise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Task.Run does *not* create a thread. It schedules a delegate to run on a ThreadPool thread. The threads in a threadpool are created or destroyed according to the CPU load.

The exit code you see has nothing really to do with your code: it may simply be a Visual Studio debug message, or a ThreadPool thread that exited.

Additionally, `async` doesn't mean that a method will run asynchronously. It is syntactic sugar that allows the compiler to create code to wait asynchronously for any asynchronous methods marked with `await`. In your case, `DoOnThread` has no asynchronous calls or `await` so it will run syncrhonously.

In fact, the compiler will even emit a warning that `DoOnThread` doesn't contain `await` so it will run synchronously

Comment: It schedules a *delegate*, which may or may not be lambda.

Comment: Thank you, Task.Run causes the action to execute on a thread different to the UI thread.  I have verified this by checking the Managed Thread ID of both the button click and the DoOnthread methods.  I was just concerned that exit code 259 was a problem, but it seems I should just ignore it.

Answer (score 9):

Thread pool threads do not belong to you. You should not set their `Name`, nor should you be concerned about their exit codes.

Comment: Yes thanks, I only named it so I could identify it easily for this simple test.  However point taken.