# Unity windows phone game crashes on scene load

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone

I have a scene which has around 10 prefabs being intantiated at start. When I switch from the previous scene to this one the game crashes. I have no idea why. I tried debugging mode in Visual Studio, but it was no help. This is the output log.

```
WARNING: Async debugging features are unavailable for this debug session because ETW event collection could not be enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\TrippyBubble.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\WinRTBridge.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\BridgeInterface.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\UnityPlayer.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\UnityEngine.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\Assembly-UnityScript.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\Boo.Lang.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\UnityEngine.UI.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\UnityScript.Lang.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{B89FE9EE-B6B1-49FA-BD9E-6E8842CBA4CF}\Install\WinRTLegacy.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x6ac has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[2548] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2147220978 (0x8004020e).
```

I tried disabling the instantiation of the objects and building it again. No change it is exactly the same. Crashes. It used to work before and I haven't changed any settings as far as I remember.

Comment: there is not enough to go on here, "thread exited" is a very generic error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887864/what-is-a-thread-exit-code

Comment: So what might be the problem. I am still not sure. Thankyou for answering though. I've been stuck on this for long. Please help me

Comment: it could be almost anything, try to narrow it down by debugging (if it was "no help" try again and observe what is happening and where it is crashing)

Comment: Does it work in Unity Editor? That should give you an idea. Either way, post your code so we can take a look to see if it's a code issue. The stack above is way too generic as LearnCocos2D says.

Comment: No o tried disabling the code. It still doesn't work. I know for sure it isn't a code specific error. And yeah it runs in the editor. Perfectly

Comment: Hi, this is a bug has been [fixed](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/uwp-crash-with-net-native-when-exception-is-thrown-from-native-code?_ga=1.28645311.2038063121.1477127252) on Unity 5.5.0B9.