# Program do not stop after close Window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Program do not stop after close Window: I write some code wich runs (into big WPF app) when main window starts. 
When I close window- I execute Dispose.

App closes, but Visual Studio still running. And I get some messages in Output:

> The thread 0x1424 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

So, I think that app is still running. If I comment my part of code (it is part of big WPF app) - Visual Studio stop running app and i can Start again.

I know, that I have not much info, but what means:

> The thread 0x1424 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

How to know what part of code it executes?

P.S. i mean that when i close app (running from VS)- MyApp.vshost.exe still running.

Comment: Code 0 means that the code exited safely. Also have a look here [Thread Code 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887864/what-is-a-thread-exit-code)

Comment: To see which threads are running you can pause the debugger and then open the threads window.