# How to prevent debugger to be stopped when Tab is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have an ASP.NET MVC - Application which uses "IisExpress" when debugging. When I Debug (<kbd>F5</kbd>) the project, a new tab opens in browser.

When I now close **any** tab in that browser (not the one, that runs the website I try to debug), debugging ends immediately. I am using Chrome but I don't expect this to be browser-specific.

How can this be changed?

**Update1**: It may be worth mentioning that the Solution has multiple Startup-Projects, one of them a SharePoint Add-in

**Update2**: The following is been written to the output log when closing a tab and just before debugging stopps.:

```
The program '[4208] chrome.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[15492] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10364] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[12380] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[10076] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[8060] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[8076] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7488] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7636] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[12972] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[15492] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[7384] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7468] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7476] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7884] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[13360] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[9768] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[13804] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[11008] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[6920] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7364] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7372] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7392] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7400] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7420] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7936] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[1900] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[8496] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[6288] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[6616] chrome.exe' has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

(But chrome is not really exited) but still running

When I start the project without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), closing a tab does not seem to have an affect on IISExpress (the application continues)

**Update3**:
Surprisingly this only happens when I close a tab that existed **before** I started debugging. Creating new tabs and closing those does **not** cause the debugger to stop.

Comment: This does not look to be as the default behavior at all. At least I never had such an issue and never heard of it, so it seems something is doing this "feature" for you.

Comment: My colleques have the same issue and we have no specific addins in VS

Comment: Which Visual Studio version?

Comment: @CodeCaster updated the tags

Comment: [Exit code 259 (0x103) means the thread is still running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887864/what-is-a-thread-exit-code). Besides that, as far as I remember, the Chrome process only runs very shortly as it passes the startup parameters (URL, ...) to the already running instance, which in turn opens a new tab. Maybe some Chrome update changed this, and Visual Studio still relies on the old behavior.

Comment: Do you have Edit And Continue enabled on the project?  In IIS Express, switch this *off* to have the app continue running when all "attached" browsers have disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a default feature of IE, if all the tabs running the application is closed, the debugger is stopped. For an workaround, we did the following once:

- Hosted the application in IIS, so the application is actually running whether we debug or not.
- When the application is running, attach debugger to the IIS worker process(w3wp.exe).
- This prevents the dependency on browser close, the debugger stays attached as long as the IIS worker process is running.

Hope it helps...

Comment: My issue is on chrome, but using the IIS might help here, too

Comment: Yes, using IIS should help you there too...but I mentioned IE as we only faced it there...

Comment: @OleAlbers any luck?

Comment: Not yet. Currently have others (more urgent) errors to fix. Will report